# Is there a way to query AWS RDS instance by its tag values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As per this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html, you can only filter RDS instances with the following filters
--filters (list)

```
db-cluster-id
db-instance-id
dbi-resource-id 
domain
engine
```

In my AWS environment, I have consistent tags for the service/application and env. Thus, **I want to retrieve RDS instances by their tags** similar to what we do with EC2s.

Has someone gotten around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanna get all the RDS instances that have tag key `TAG_KEY` and tag value `TAG_VAL`:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[?contains(TagList[].Key, `TAG_KEY`) && contains(TagList[].Value, `TAG_VAL`)]'
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much!!
I could query multiple tags with two query commands, but is there a way to combine it all ? 
```aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[?contains(TagList[].Key, `A`) && contains(TagList[].Value, `B`)]' --query 'DBInstances[?contains(TagList[].Key, `X`) && contains(TagList[].Value, `Y`)]'```

Comment: @VinitaShah ```aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[?contains(TagList[].Key, `A`) && contains(TagList[].Value, `B`) && contains(TagList[].Key, `X`) && contains(TagList[].Value, `Y`)]'```

Comment: This is not 100% accurate. If you want k/v pair A=a and resource has tags A=b, B=a the query ?contains(TagList[].Key, `A`) && contains(TagList[].Value, `a`) will return the resource incorrectly

Comment: This checks key and value separately, not in the same tag

Answer (score 0):

You could conider using *jq* which filters the tag name and value within the tags (and not independently as separate lists):

```
aws rds describe-db-instances | jq '.DBInstances | map(select(.TagList[] | .Name == "tagName", .Value == "tagValue")) | .[].DBInstanceIdentifier'
```

Multiple tags:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances | jq '.DBInstances | map(select(.TagList[] | .Name == "tagName", .Value == "tagValue")) | map(select(.TagList[] | .Name == "tagName2", .Value == "tagValue2")) | .[].DBInstanceIdentifier'
```